# Multiple SQL columns into 1 json column

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am new to querying and using JSON fields. I've done some research, but most of the info I find is regarding querying from JSON to rows and columns. My question is in opposite direction:

Let's say I have a table with 3 columns: (Age, Optin, City). Now i want to add one column in JSON format. I tried:

```
SELECT Age, Optin, City
INTO #JSON_Table
FROM MyTable
FOR JSON AUTO
```

> Error message: Msg 13602, Level 16, State 1, Line 30 The FOR JSON
>   clause is not allowed in a SELECT INTO statement.

Pretty basic stuff, I know, but I could use some assistence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * into #JSON_Table
from (SELECT Age, Optin, City
FROM MyTable
FOR JSON PATH
) a(X)
```

Where X is the column name

Comment: Thanks, I accepted this answer. One additional question: can I get the result such that for each person I get 1 row with the JSON column containing these 3 attributes?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Can you write a sample output json that you want?

Comment: I will try.  :)  ROW 1: PersonID 1, JSON_Field {Age:18, Optin:1, City:Rotterdam}. ROW 2 PersonID 2 JSON_Field {Age: 24, Optin: 0, City: New York}. Something like that I guess. Does that make sense?

Comment: select * into #JSON_Table
from (SELECT PersonID, Age [MyTable.Age], Optin [MyTable.Optin], City [MyTable.City]
FROM MyTable
FOR JSON PATH
) a(X)

Comment: Thanks again, this throws an error: invalid column names.

Comment: There should be actual columns in this names.Please check the column names.I created a table and columns in these names and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and also check with the sql server versions. some versions of sql like SQL SERVER 2012 doesn't supports this query and 2016 will does.

`select * into #JSON_Table
from (SELECT Age, Optin, City
FROM MyTable
FOR JSON PATH
) a`

Comment: Thanks for your assistence. However, I get an error message: Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 29
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'J'.
Msg 1038, Level 15, State 5, Line 25
An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.